# Excel VBA Setting source data of chart using .SetSourceData

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I'm trying to update the source data range of charts in my sheet, but I'm getting runtime error '445'. Documentation claims that `Chartobject.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range` should be valid, but why is my code failing when I try and set the source data of FirstChart? I also get a different error (-2147467259 80004005) when I add in a `PlotBy` modifier to SecondChart.

Here's my code.

```
Public Sub ReGenerateCharts()

Dim Ws As Worksheet
Set Ws = Worksheets("Chart Sheet")
Dim FirstBottomCell As Long

Dim SecondBottomCell As Long

Dim FirstSourceData As Range
Dim SecondSourceData As Range

Dim FirstChart As ChartObject
Dim SecondChart As ChartObject

With Ws
    Set FirstChart = .ChartObjects("Chart 1")
    Set SecondChart = .ChartObjects("Chart 2")
    
    FirstBottomCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row
    SecondBottomCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 24).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set FirstSourceData = .Range(.Cells(4, 15), .Cells(FirstBottomCell, 15))
    Set SecondSourceData = .Range(.Cells(4, 24), .Cells(SecondBottomCell, 24))

End With
FirstChart.Chart.ChartType = xlHistogram
SecondChart.Chart.ChartType = xlHistogram

FirstChart.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=FirstSourceData
SecondChart.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=SecondSourceData, PlotBy:=xlRows
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `FirstChart.Chart.SetSourceData`  - `SetSourceData` is a member of a `Chart`, not a `ChartObject`.

Comment: What type of charts are these?

Comment: Histograms, the default charts inserted from the ribbon.

Comment: The chart already has a a range of values selected, do I need to use a different member to _update_ the source data?